# ReporteRs crashing Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, reporters

I am trying to create a powerpoint in R using ReporteRs. I've created my graphs using ggplot2. I installed ReporteRs without issue and I can create a new pptx, add a slide and title, but when it gets to the `addPlot` Rstudio works on it a bit before crashing, giving me the message that R Studio aborted and encountered a fatal error. Has anyone experienced this before? Here is my code for the ReporteRs:

```
install.packages("ReporteRs")
library(ReporteRs)
WinR = pptx()
slide.layouts(WinR)
WinR = addSlide(WinR,"Title and Content")
WinR = addTitle(WinR, "Effect of Time on Total Root Length")
WinR = addPlot(WinR, Lengthplotfinal)`
```

`Lengthplotfinal` is the bar graph developed prior

Thank you!

Comment: Reports of crashes should go to RStudio. Don't terminate code blocks with a backtick. And cannot reproduce. Only get an error: `object 'Lengthplotfinal' not foundError in vector.pptx.graphic(doc = doc, fun = fun, pointsize = pointsize,  : 
  an error occured when executing plot function.` Running not in RStudio but rather in the Mac GUI.

Comment: ReporteRs is now deprecated. You might like to take a look at my new export package that uses officer as a backend to easily export graphs to Powerpoint, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html and https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've reproduced your error and changing your `addPlot` line to the one below appears to work.

See the examples at http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/addPlot.html

```
library(ReporteRs)
library(ggplot2)

#example plot
c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar()


WinR = pptx()
slide.layouts(WinR)
WinR = addSlide(WinR,"Title and Content")
WinR = addTitle(WinR, "Effect of Time on Total Root Length")
WinR = addPlot(doc = WinR, x = c, fun = print)
writeDoc( WinR, "example.pptx" )
```